# PagingAndSortingRepository findFooInBar call by url

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have recently started using spring-boot with a PagingAndSortingRepository.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "foobar", path = "foobar")
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<FooEntity, Long>{

    List<FooEntity> findAllByStatusIn(@Param("stati") Collection<Integer> stati);

}
```

How would I call `findAllByStatusIn` via a url call like `http://localhost:8080/foobar/search/findAllByStatusIn?stati={3,1}`

I have already tried:

`http://localhost:8080/foobar/search/findAllByStatusIn?stati=(3,1)`

`http://localhost:8080/foobar/search/findAllByStatusIn?stati=[3,1]`

`http://localhost:8080/foobar/search/findAllByStatusIn?stati={3,1}`

`http://localhost:8080/foobar/search/findAllByStatusIn?stati=3,1`

Comment: Where is your controller class?

Comment: It exists, yes. But the url is not created by a controller, but by spring-boots implementation of the PagingAndSortingRepository.

Comment: You can't call this method directly.you have to call it from controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying my PagingAndSortingRepository slightly:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "pstnachrichten", path = "pstnachrichten")
public interface PSTNachrichtenRepository extends     PagingAndSortingRepository<PSTNachrichtenEntity, Long>{

    List<PSTNachrichtenEntity> findAllByStatusIn(@Param("stati") int... stati);

}
```

I was able to call the resource as follows:

`http://localhost:8080/foobar/search/findAllByStatusIn?stati=3&stati=1`

The trick was thus to just repeat the name value pair in the url.